# insert_rows_json with write truncate

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I'm working on a small python script to write data I get from an API into a BigQuery table. I only have a small amount of data. Data from the API are updated on daily basis. I want to be able to overwrite the table destination with the most recent data everyday.

I have the following script in a cloud function:

```
  data = {'col': 'value'} # the JSON response I get from the API (simplified output)

  job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema = [
      bigquery.SchemaField("col", "STRING"),
    ],
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
  )     

  job = bq_client.insert_rows_json(table_id, [data], job_config=job_config)
```

and the following error `Client.insert_rows_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'job_config'`

Should I use a different method than `insert_rows_json()`? What's the best way to write these new data everyday in the same table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the best way, but you can't pass `JobConfig` with `WRITE_TRUNCATE` mode. You have to execute a separated query to `truncate` the table, then append all your dicts to `BigQuery` with `insert_rows_json` :

```
data = {'col': 'value'} # the JSON response I get from the API (simplified output)

# Truncate the table
bq_client = bigquery.Client()
query_job = bq_client.query(f"TRUNCATE table {table_id}")

results = query_job.result()

# Append your Dict from api to BQ
job = bq_client.insert_rows_json(table_id, [data])
```

The `insert_rows_json` uses the following [insertAll api](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll).